# IISReset to remote server fails

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, windows-7

I'm attempting to run `iisreset 192.168.100.182` (against a Windows Server 2003 machine) from another machine *on the same domain* (running Windows 7 Professional) and am receiving the following error message:

> Attempting stop...
>
> Restart attempt failed. Access denied, you must be an
>   administrator of the remote computer
>   to use this command. Either have your
>   account added to the administrator
>   local group of the remote computer or
>   to the domain administrator global
>   group.

I'm running the command from an *elevated command prompt* with my domain account added to the *Administrators* group on the target machine. I've attempted this when being a member of the administrators group both directly and by virtue of membership of a domain group that's a member of the administrators group.

I've reviewed the event log on the target machine and it shows a selection of *Success Audits* for my domain credentials immediately after attempting the iisreset, but no failure audits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to confirm (by installing another 2003 box), after determining that the problem doesn't occur on my home network, that this appears to be an issue specific to the configuration of the server concerned.

The solution in this instance is to re-install the operating system.

For anyone that encounters this in the future, another symptom I've identified is that the process "iisrstas" gets created on the server, under the context of the user performing the IISReset remotely and never exits.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using psexec to do this.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553

Also check the local security policy for the remote machine, you may only be logging success events and not failures.

secpol.msc -> Local Policies -> Audit Policy.

Audit Logon Events should be set to Success and Failure to see the Fails in the event log.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this myself in my own environment - as far as I can tell you can only carry out a remote reset of IIS from the command line from another Server 2003 or Windows XP machine.

The command line utilities in Windows 7 / Server 2008 are not compatible, even after installing the IIS6 Compatibility tools.

The only reliable way I've found to reset IIS from a Windows 7 Machine is to use the IIS6 Manager GUI.

Comment: Any machine with IIS 5 + installed on it has the IISReset command.

Comment: I'm afraid that isn't quite right, I've just run an iisreset from my primary PC at home (Win7) to a virtual server on my media centre (Win2k3), all of which are domain joined and the IISReset ran without error, so it's not a "can't ever work", more a "doesn't work under a given circumstance".

Comment: I quite happily stand corrected on that then - I just can't seem to make it work full stop.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar frustrations, and the gotcha I had was that my accounts was not in a domain controlled environment, and my userId's and passwords was different between machines.

So, if **you are not in a Domain** Controlled environment, I suggest making sure that the users that you are using, have Local Admin on both machines, and the username and passwords match.

**If you are doing it in a domain environment**, do make sure that your user is added as a local admin on the server. Not just an administrator, he has to be a part of the local admins group.

After that you should be able to to `IISRESET [computername] /RESTART`

If you have any issues, check that your local firewalls on the computers are not blocking RPC.

Comment: I thought I made it quite clear in my question that I'm working in a domain environment AND have added my domain account to the Administrators group directly **and** indirectly? There is no firewall enabled on either the target server or my desktop machine.

Comment: @Rob: No need to have that tone man, I am trying to help you, AND others reading this post after you that is not on a domain. What happens if you iisreset 192.168.100.182 /STOP and then iisreset 192.168.100.182 /START

Comment: exactly the same as without /STOP or /START, the error message I detail in my question is presented.